# How to send input field value to Node JS backend via AJAX call for typeahead functionality

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, typeahead.js

I am trying to implement a typeahead functionality as below.

**html page**

```
...
...
    <input id="product" name="product" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Product Name" autocomplete="off">
...
...  
    <script>
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    fetchTypeAheadResult();
                });

                function fetchTypeAheadResult() {
                    $('#product').typeahead({
                        source: function (request, response) {
                          var formData = {
                            'product' : $('#product').val()
                          }
                          // var formData = $('form').serialize();
                          $.ajax({
                                url: "/search",
                                dataType: "json",
                                type: "POST",
                                data: formData,
                                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                success: function (result) {
                                    var items = [];
                                    response($.map(result, function (item) {                            
                                        items.push(item.name);
                                    }))
                                    response(items);

                                    // SET THE WIDTH AND HEIGHT OF UI AS "auto" ALONG WITH FONT.
                                    // YOU CAN CUSTOMIZE ITS PROPERTIES.
                                    $(".dropdown-menu").css("width", "100%");
                                    $(".dropdown-menu").css("height", "auto");
                                    $(".dropdown-menu").css("font", "12px Verdana");
                                },
                                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                                    alert(textStatus);
                                }
                            });
                        },
                        hint: true,             // SHOW HINT (DEFAULT IS "true").
                        highlight: true,        // HIGHLIGHT (SET <strong> or <b> BOLD). DEFAULT IS "true".
                        minLength: 1            // MINIMUM 1 CHARACTER TO START WITH.
                    });
                }
            </script>
...
...
```

And my back end **node js code** is as following

```
    'use strict';
    const express = require('express');
    const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    const request = require('request');
    const app = express();

    // configure the app to use bodyParser() to extract body from request.
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
    // parse various different custom JSON types as JSON
    app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/*+json' }));

     app.post('/search', (req, res) => {
      let searchText = req.body;

    console.log('Search string >> ' + req);
    console.log('Search string >> ' + JSON.stringify(req.body));
    console.log('Search string >> ' + req.body.product);

// Not correct, but still trying if it works
      // var result = triestrct.get(req.body.product);
      res.send({test:'text'});    // TODO - to be updated with correct json 
    });
```

Now whenever I am trying to type on the "product" text field, it is invoking the back end /search api. However, I am unable to capture the value of product field.

Any help will be appreciated ? Note, I need typeahed functionality with ajax call to send input text value to back end.

**Output** of the three consol logs as following...

```
Search string >> [object Object]
Search string >> {}
Search string >> undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

`express` doesn't parse the input provided to API by it self. Thus we need some additional tool like `body-parser` to fetch input from request and format it into `JSON`. This can be done without `body-parser` too.

Do go through this [documentation](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/anatomy-of-an-http-transaction/#request-body) it covers a lot.

1. Using `body-parser`, you need to setup `body-parser` with `express`:

```

```
const bodyParser                  = require('body-parser'),
// For Cross-Origin Resource Sharing
      CORS                        = require('cors'),
        express                     = require('express');

  const app                         = express();

  // Cross-Origin Resource Sharing
  app.use(CORS());

  // configure the app to use bodyParser() to extract body from request.
  // parse urlencoded types to JSON
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
  }));

  // parse various different custom JSON types as JSON
  app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/*+json' }));

  // parse some custom thing into a Buffer
  app.use(bodyParser.raw({ type: 'application/vnd.custom-type' }));

  // parse an HTML body into a string
  app.use(bodyParser.text({ type: 'text/html' }));


  // This will get you input at `req.body`

 app.post('/search',(req,res)=>{
     console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body));
 });
```

```

2. Without using `body-parser`:

```

```
app.post('/', (req, res, next) => {

    let body = [];

    req.on('error', (err) => {
        console.error(err);
    }).on('data', (chunk) => {
        // Without parsing data it's present in chunks.
        body.push(chunk);
    }).on('end', () => {
        // Finally converting data into readable form
        body = Buffer.concat(body).toString();

        console.log(body);

        // Setting input back into request, just same what body-parser do.
        req.body = body;
        next();
    });

}, (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
});
```

```

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not working. Can you please revisit my current code (updated) once again and provide suggestion ? Thank You in advance.

Comment: What was output of `console.log('Search string >> ' + searchText);`

Comment: Search string >> [object Object]
Search string >> {}
Search string >> undefined

also, modified the question with output logs.

Comment: Yes, I just tried and it is capturing req.body only . But, not as usual JSON format. It is returning as product=abc. My expectation was {product : abc}. In addition, req.product.body is 'undefined'.
Any better solution to capture body as true JSON ? Also, if it uses body-parser would be great.

Comment: The way you are setting `headers` in ajax call. use `headers: {'Content-Type': 'applcation/json'}`.

Comment: When you get data like product=abc means it's urlencoded data.

Comment: Yes, I used headers: {'Content-Type': 'applcation/json'} . Also, I set app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })); Still, I could not get it as JSON format.

Answer (score 0):

`req.body.product` not `req.query.product`

IN POST verb use [body-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser) midlleware

```
const bodyParser = requier('body-parser');
const express = require('express');
const app = new express();

// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.post('/search',(req,res)=>{
console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body));
});
```

I did not use typeahead before but this [example](http://www.runningcoder.org/jquerytypeahead/demo/) is clear.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I tried you code but it did not work :( Can you please revisit my updated code and suggest further ?

Comment: what was the output of `console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body));`